# php require class (undefined or fatal error)

Tags: php, undefined, require, phpstorm, fatal-error

I am fairly new to PHP OOP and I can't seem to get my class files to require correctly. Whenever I attempt to require them I get a fatal error. Furthermore, phpstorm says my classes are undefined. The Path to location shows up as valid as phpstorm isn't saying path not found. But when run the classes can't be found.

ToyPlansV1.0/TestMain.php  --> This class calls setup on the Test class
ToyPlansV1.0/includes/DatabaseHandler.php -->Underlying class to be tested
ToyPlansV1.0/includes/TestClasses/DBHandlerTest.php -->This class is the Test class

Contents of TestMain.php

```
<?php
    require ("includes/TestClasses/DBHandlerTest.php");
    $DBTest = new DBHandlerTest();
    $DBTest.Setup();
?>
```

Contents of DBHandlerTest.php

```
<?php
    namespace includes\TestClasses;
    require("../DatabaseHandler.php");
    class DBHandlerTest {
        protected $DB;
        protected function Setup(){
        $this->$DB = new DatabaseHandler();
    }
}
```

The errors I get when running TestMain.php are:

require(../DatabaseHandler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\ToyPlansV1.0\includes\TestClasses\DBHandlerTest.php on line 3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../DatabaseHandler.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\ToyPlansV1.0\includes\TestClasses\DBHandlerTest.php on line 3

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../DatabaseHandler.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\ToyPlansV1.0\includes\TestClasses\DBHandlerTest.php on line 3

Any ideas where I am going wrong / how to fix the require paths?

EDIT updated code, nearly working.

```
<?php
//require ("includes/TestClasses/DBHandlerTest.php");
require(__DIR__.'/includes/TestClasses/DBHandlerTest.php');
use includes\TestClasses\DBHandlerTest As DBHandlerTest;
$DBTest = new DBHandlerTest();
$DBTest.Setup();
?>

<?php
namespace includes\TestClasses;
require(__DIR__.'/../DatabaseHandler.php');
use includes\DatabaseHandler As DatabaseHandler;
class DBHandlerTest
{
    protected $DB;
    public function Setup()
    {
        $this->$DB = new DatabaseHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly on the disk are each of the files that fail to load?

Comment: c:\wamp\www\ToyPlansv1.0\includes\TestClasses\DBHandlerTest.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TestMain.php you have to declare your `DBHandlerTest` class with `use` like this:

```
require (__DIR__.'/includes/TestClasses/DBHandlerTest.php');

use includes\TestClasses\DBHandlerTest As DBHandlerTest;

$DBTest = new DBHandlerTest();
$DBTest->Setup();
```

And in DBHandlerTest.php, you have to make your `Setup()` method `public`:

```
namespace includes\TestClasses;

require(__DIR__.'/../DatabaseHandler.php');

class DBHandlerTest
{
    protected $DB;

    public function Setup()
    {
        $this->$DB = new DatabaseHandler();
    }
}
```

This will work, but apart from that you should use [spl_autoload_register](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). It will make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed one of the fatal errors. However if I insert this into TestMain.php
    require(__DIR__.'/includes/TestClasses/DBHandlerTest.php');
I get
     PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DBHandlerTest' not found in C:\wamp\www\ToyPlansV1.0\TestMain.php on line 4

Comment: Did you notice it is `(__DIR__.'/something')`, not `('DIR.'/something'))` ?

Comment: Yes, I just can't get it to display right in the stack overflow comment box.

Comment: It's a namespace problem. I edited my answer. Is it correct now?

Comment: It fixed the first error, however now I get:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Setup() in C:\wamp\www\ToyPlansV1.0\TestMain.php on line 6

Comment: @user3263206 Yes, because SetUp() was a `protected` method. You have to make it `public` to let other classes that don't inherit from DBHandlerTest access it. See my edit.

Comment: I've changed the method visibility to public but still says method is undefined. Thanks Jivan for all your help so far :)

Comment: @user3263206 it is a typo. You call for `Setup()` but the method name is `SetUp()`. Choose one :)

Comment: I fixed the typo, still have the same error. Posted updated code.

Comment: Well, must be another typo somewhere then :)

Comment: Oh thanks, I forgot the dot operator is -> in php. Thanks so much Jivan :)